# Get the word before a semicolon from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the below string:

`Consolidation CompletedThe Scenario is LDP; the Year is 2018; the Start Period is July; the End Period is June; the Entity is TOT_NEWS.`

And need to get the words just before the `semicolon (;)` and the last word before the `dot (.)`

```
Result:
-----  ----  ----  ----  ----
LDP    2018  July  June  TOT_NEWS
```

I could obtain the first one `LDP` with the below select:

```
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strDescription, CHARINDEX('The Scenario 
is', strDescription,+39), 
CHARINDEX(';',strDescription,-1))), CHARINDEX (' ', 
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(strDescription, 
CHARINDEX('The Scenario is', strDescription,+39), 
CHARINDEX(';',strDescription,-1)))))) as Scenario
```

But it doesn´t work for the rest of the string.

Comment: Is there a fixed number of semicolons?

Comment: Is SQL really the tool you need to use for this?

Comment: @Lamak Yes, it´s always the same number.

Comment: @TZHX Yes, we need this script for SQL Server databases.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: @TZHX SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: SQL sucks at string manipulation so nothing's going to be pretty. But I'd split the string on semicolons (you'll have to handle the period separately, but since that's tat the end, it's probably easier to get at). See this article if you're not sure how to split strings in SQL. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Is CLR an option? This kind of string manipulation is nasty in sql server but super simple (and fast) with a CLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
-- Defining your string
DECLARE @string varchar(max)
SET @string = 'Consolidation CompletedThe Scenario is LDP; the Year is 2018; the Start Period is July; the End Period is June; the Entity is TOT_NEWS.'


;with pos as (
SELECT 
 @string as String
,CHARINDEX(';', @string, 1) as Pos_1
,CHARINDEX(';', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string, 1)+1) as Pos_2
,CHARINDEX(';', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string, 1)+1)+1) as Pos_3
,CHARINDEX(';', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string, CHARINDEX(';', @string, 1)+1)+1)+1) as Pos_4
) , txt as (
select 
 String
,substring(String, 1,Pos_1-1) as String_1
,substring(String,Pos_1+1,Pos_2-Pos_1-1) as String_2
,substring(String,Pos_2+1,Pos_3-Pos_2-1) as String_3
,substring(String,Pos_3+1,Pos_4-Pos_3-1) as String_4
,substring(String,Pos_4+1,LEN(String)-Pos_4-1) as String_5
from pos
) 
SELECT
 string
,substring(String_1,len(String_1)-charindex(' ',reverse(String_1),1)+1,charindex(' ',reverse(String_1))) as Result_1
,substring(String_2,len(String_2)-charindex(' ',reverse(String_2),1)+1,charindex(' ',reverse(String_2))) as Result_2
,substring(String_3,len(String_3)-charindex(' ',reverse(String_3),1)+1,charindex(' ',reverse(String_3))) as Result_3
,substring(String_4,len(String_4)-charindex(' ',reverse(String_4),1)+1,charindex(' ',reverse(String_4))) as Result_4
,substring(String_5,len(String_5)-charindex(' ',reverse(String_5),1)+1,charindex(' ',reverse(String_5))) as Result_5
from txt
```

Output:

```
string                                                                                                                                  |  Result_1 | Result_2 | Result_3 | Result_4 | Result_5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------|----------|----------|----------|---------
Consolidation CompletedThe Scenario is LDP; the Year is 2018; the Start Period is July; the End Period is June; the Entity is TOT_NEWS. |  LDP      | 2018     | July     | June     | TOT_NEWS
```

Comment: This produces the correct output but if this is a large dataset the performance is going to be pretty poor. Reverse is a horribly slow function and just the shear amount of functions here will not let this scale well. But it does work.

Comment: Yes, and of course you can't read it very well... but i wanted to use the functions he used and the result is in a row in this case - and if you only read a variable it is a constant scan vs. 3 nested loops in the split ;-) but yes - i totally aggree and i would not recommend this with a big amount of data!

Comment: Well ideally the OP will fix their horrible data and stop storing delimited information like this and there would be no need for splitting it anyway. :)

Comment: Thank you It works! And I know it will affect performance which is not good. So far it will work for what I need but If you know another way to do it, it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using a string splitter...

```
declare @value varchar(max) = 'Consolidation CompletedThe Scenario is LDP; the Year is 2018; the Start Period is July; the End Period is June; the Entity is TOT_NEWS.'

;with cte as(
select
* from
dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@value,';'))

select
    replace(right(Item,charindex(' ',reverse(Item),1)),'.','')
from cte
```

**THE FUNCTION**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K] (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!

RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN

/* "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)*/

  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

[Creator of the Function](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

Comment: Shoot, that got cut off of the bottom when i copied and pasted. Thanks for the heads up @SeanLange

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to a TVF (Table-Valued Function).

This approach uses a modifed split/parse function.  Rather than one delimeter, I use two non-like delimiters.  It this case a `' '` and `';'`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,strDescription varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'Consolidation CompletedThe Scenario is LDP; the Year is 2018; the Start Period is July; the End Period is June; the Entity is TOT_NEWS.')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
              Select Pos1 = max(case when RetSeq=1 then RetVal end)
                    ,Pos2 = max(case when RetSeq=2 then RetVal end)
                    ,Pos3 = max(case when RetSeq=3 then RetVal end)
                    ,Pos4 = max(case when RetSeq=4 then RetVal end)
                    ,Pos5 = max(case when RetSeq=5 then RetVal end)
               From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.strDescription+';',' ',';')
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Pos1    Pos2    Pos3    Pos4    Pos5
1   LDP     2018    July    June    TOT_NEWS
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: i actually saved this last time i saw it from you, and forgot about it. dang it haha. 1 from me